# Table not shown up on Linked Server

Tags: sql-server-2000, sql-server-express

I have a machine which have 2 SQLServer instances

- `WINXP-PRO\SQLSERVER2000` (SQL Server 2000)
- `WINXP-PRO\SQLEXPRESS` (SQL Server 2005 Express Edition).

In `\SQLEXPRESS`, I have database wavinet2 and wavinet2_mapic. In `\SQLSERVER2000`, I create linked server to `[IP_ADDRESS]\SQLEXPRESS`, the linked server is created.

All tables have shown up except for database `wavinet_mapic`.

I provide the remote login using `sa`. I try to select and it cannot found the table.

Any hint what is causing this problem?

Comment: What is the compatibility level set to on the 2005 instance databases?

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that the table in question uses a feature that is only available in SQL Server 2005 and above and so that is why you cannot see it in your 2000 instance. This is similar to what happens when you try to open a SQL 2005 or above instance from Enterprise Manager - except you get a more descriptive error. If you desperately need to see this table in SQL 2000 remove the offending feature (if at all possible) from the table (it might just be a data type), if you cannot remove the feature then have a think about whether it is possible to have the link the opposite way around?

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the error?  Without the error, my first thought would be to check the permissions on the sa account for that table (ensuring the user has access to SELECT the table).  Along the same lines, I would also check to see if the linked server has all appropriate permissions for that table too.

Comment: There are no Error message because the linked server is crated successfully. Except that I can't see tables from database wavinet_mapic. I login using the sa account (which means superuser in sql, CMIIW) but I'll take a look again with the permission